# Does anybody know from where the "layer of abstraction"/"layer of indirection" quote emerged?

Tags: computer-science, quotes

The quote goes something like this:

> There's no problem in Computer Science
>   that can't be solved by adding another
>   layer of  abstraction to it

(Copied in this wording from http://blogs.oracle.com/fcmartin/2009/01/pardon_my_dust.html)

There are a number of variations but I have been unable to find an originator. Since I quite like the quote with its tongue in cheek and quite a bit of truth, I would be interested to hear if anybody knows where this may come from.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[This website](http://www.purpletech.com/maxims.jsp) attributes it to [David Wheeler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_(computer_scientist)), who worked on EDSAC among his other early accomplishments. His Wikipedia bio also suggests he might have originated it. This is probably your best bet.

The form they give is:

> Any problem in computer science can be solved with another layer of indirection. But that usually will create another problem

I first heard it when I was a CS freshman in '85 while our instructor was introducing pointers in our CS101 course. I got the impression it was a canard even then.

If anyone is looking to attribute it to someone, it had better be someone at least moderately famous back in '85. That *probably* rules out Koenig.

Comment: You have a point. Now it's easy, just email your instructor and ask him...:-)

Answer (score 8):

I like this version better:

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of
>   indirection... Except for the problem of too many layers of
>   indirection.
>
> [David Wheeler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_%28computer_scientist%29)

Insightful... So remember: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

Answer (score 3):

The better known quote is:

> There's no problem in Computer Science
>   that can't be solved by adding another
>   **level of indirection** to it

Not sure where it came from, but I have a vague memory that Andrew Koenig had something to do with it.

**Edit:** And it seems to be so - see [this review](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184404549) of his and his wife's excellent book Acclerated C++ in Dr Dobbs.

Comment: That doesn't say that he originated it, just that he likes to say it. It is pretty unlikely that he originated it (for reasons I get into in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I've found these terms at:

- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering):

> ## Fundamental theorem of software engineering
>
> The fundamental theorem of software engineering (FTSE) is a term originated by [Andrew Koenig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Koenig_(programmer)) to describe a remark by [Butler Lampson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butler_Lampson) attributed to the late [David J. Wheeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_(computer_scientist)):
>
> > *"We can solve any problem by introducing an extra **level of indirection**."*
>
> The theorem does not describe an actual theorem that can be proven; rather, it is a general principle for managing complexity through abstraction.
>
> The theorem is often expanded by the humorous clause:
>
> > *"…except for the problem of too many **levels of indirection**,"*
>
> referring to the fact that too many abstractions may create intrinsic complexity issues of their own.

- [RFC 1925](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1925) (year 1996):

  which is an [*"April Fools' Day  RFC"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day_Request_for_Comments) and here is the relative section:

> ## The Twelve Networking Truths
>
> (6)  It is easier to move a problem around (for example, by moving
> the problem to a different part of the overall network
> architecture) than it is to solve it.
>
> - (6a) (corollary). It is always possible to add another **level of indirection**.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it attributed to Andrew Koenig.