# Capturing method argument type and ask for corresponding class object

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Given the following scenario

```
class Base { }
class Extended extends Base {}
```

I can easily ask for a class object in a generic class's constructor that is some **subclass** of the generic type.

```
class Test<T extends Base> {
  Test(Class<? extends T> test) { }
}
```

This way I can do all of the following

```
new Test<Base>(Base.class);
new Test<Base>(Extended.class);
new Test<Extended>(Base.class); // This is not allowed by the compiler
new Test<Extended>(Extended.class);
```

what is exactly what I want. However, I cannot figure out how I can achieve the same constraint when using a generic methods like this:

```
<T extends Base> void test(T x, Class<? extends T> test) { }
```

With this definition, all of the following are permitted by the compiler:

```
test(new Base(), Base.class);
test(new Base(), Extended.class);
test(new Extended(), Base.class); // even though Base is not a subclass of Extended
test(new Extended, Extended.class);
```

I figure this is because of type inference and Java determining

```
<Base>test(new Extended(), Base.class)
```

instead of

```
<Extended>test(new Extended(), Base.class)
```

But how can I enforce the latter inference method?

Thanks for help!

**For future readers**: In the first version of this question I called `Base` `A` and `Extended` `B`. I later clarified this notation. This notation is however used in the answers.

Comment: Just turn the second argument into `Class<T>`?

Comment: That would prohibit `test(a, B.class)` instead of `test(b, A.class)`.

Comment: `<T extends A, U extends T> void test(U x, Class<?  T> test) { }`?

Comment: I don't get it, I thought you wanted to prohibit the Class argument to be a different class than the first argument?

Comment: No, I want the class argument to be a **subclass** of the object's class.

Comment: To clarify, please mark which of the above 4 cases should not compile. You need to let us know what should be allowed and what should not.

Comment: I assume the idea is that the class parameter functions as a type token, to force the binding of the type variable to a particular type. I further assume that the object parameter needs to be an instance of this type or one of its subtypes.

Comment: If that's the case, i would expect that the goal is for `test(b, A.class)` to be allowed, but not `test(a, B.class)`. Which is not what @raphw wrote just above.

Comment: So the `class` argument must be a **subclass** of the first argument but NOT the same class?

Comment: Okay, judging by his edit, my assumption was exactly the wrong way round. A more concrete example than `A` and `B` might have been helpful here.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: "I assume the idea is that the class parameter functions as a type token" -> This is what I want. I want to know a type which is a subtype of the first argument's type. (Assuming the academic definition of a type where every type is a subtype of itself: `test(b, B.class)` should therefore be allowed.)

Comment: I rewrote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in computer science, and as such, [can be solved by another level of indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057503/does-anybody-know-from-where-the-layer-of-abstraction-layer-of-indirection-q):

```
<T extends A, U extends T> void test(T x, Class<U> test) {}
```

In this case, we use one type variable (bounded to A) to capture the type of the object parameter, and a second one (bounded to the first) to constrain the type of the class parameter.

If i write this example out and feed it to javac (1.6.0_26), it duly tells me:

```
Test.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method test(B,java.lang.Class<A>)
location: class Test<T>
        test(b, A.class);
        ^
1 error
```

As @JohnB intimates in his comment, you can defeat this by writing:

```
this.<A, A>test(b, A.class);
```

Or by using raw types.

Comment: This would still allow `test(b, A.class)` because it would be `<A,A>`

Comment: @JohnB: That's not what my compiler says.

Comment: show the line of code where you are calling it. If you specify `<B,B>` then compile error, if you specify `<A,A>`, no compile error because `b` is an `A` and `A` extends `A`.

Comment: This actually was my solution. However, IntelliJ told me this was okay to compile. Thank's a lot!

Comment: Aha. I use Eclipse, and occasionally find that javac and Eclipse disagree about the finer points of generics. I'm not surprised to hear that IntelliJ does too. In this case, javac and Eclipse agree, so i am inclined to identify IntelliJ as the weakest link.

Comment: I now posted the bug to IntelliJ's YouTrack. Thanks once again for the answer. So happy this actually works.

Comment: Since there is a choice of type parameters that allows this to compile, this is not a "solution". It only "works" due to limited inference.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will try this in two parts. First, I don't think you can do what you want because the caller could always specify the super class as the generic and then pass a subclass as the first argument.

Second, I think trying to make this a compile-time check is the wrong approach because the user could always just choose to use a raw type and ignore all the generics. You should just make this a run-time check and provide appropriate documentation.

Comment: I provide a run time check. However, I prefer this to be validated at compile time as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are not for imposing arbitrary "restrictions". Generics are only for type safety, i.e. avoiding unsafe casts. There is no type-safety reason to have the restriction that you present. There is no function `test` in which `test(new Base(), Base.class);` would be type-safe, but `test(new Extended(), Base.class);` would not be.

Comment: The first argument of my application function is itself generic where the argument can only be of the same type. I need to know this type but this is impossible due to type erasure. Therefore it does make sence in some occasions. I did not want to make an overly complex example though and skipped this part from my question.

Comment: @raphw: No, anywhere it is safe to use a `Base`, it is safe to use an `Extended`. That is the point of inheritance. Again, I challenge you to find a function `test` where `test(new Base(), Base.class);`  would be type-safe but `test(new Extended(), Base.class);` would not be.

Comment: When they are used inside a generic type. Base<Base> is not a superclass of Base<Extended> or Extended<Extended>. My application is defined this way, I simplified the example.

Comment: @raphw: again, this has nothing to do with the parameters to the function `test`

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer is that in the first case you specify the generic type: `new Test<B>(...)`. Notice the `<B>`. However in the second case you do not specify the generic type: `test(a, A.class)` therefore you allow the compiler to see if it can determine a generic type that works. In the case of `test(b, A.class)`, `<A>` works because `b` is an instance of `A`.

Try something like: `myInstance.<B>test(b, A.class)`

Comment: The problem is: I do not want this method ever to be called other than `myInstance.<B>test(b, A.class)` because it would fail. I need the type for a reflection performed on the object. And I do not invoke the method myself, it is invoked by the users of my code.